# Split and group by xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking for some xslt help

I have following flat file from DB, I need to get the records group by the customer id(3388892, 3388893), This can be done using the following xslt provided below, however I am unable to group it. Hope someone can identify the issue and help me, thanks in advance

```
    DBSTART|ecec2b45-609c-45b5-a0cb-cc50220eeb9a|2|@|BEGIN|2|@|OUT_START|11|@
    |3388892|^|Product 1|^|4|^|1.99|^||#
    |3388892|^|Product 2|^|1|^|0.79|^||#
    |3388892|^|Product 3|^|2|^|1.22|^||#
    |3388892|^|Product 4|^|1|^|4.33|^||#
    |3388893|^|Product 1|^|1|^|1.99|^||#
    |3388893|^|Product 2|^|2|^|0.79|^||#
    |3388893|^|Product 3|^|3|^|1.22|^||#
    |OUT_END|11|@|END|2|@|DBEND|ecec2b45-609c-45b5-a0cb-cc50220eeb9a|2|@|
```

I am trying to use following xslt sylesheet, but I am failing to get my extract output.

```
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="OUT_START\|11\|.*OUT_END\|11\|">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
             <xsl:variable name="preTrim" select="."/>
             <xsl:variable name="preRows" select="replace(replace($preTrim, 'OUT_START\|[0-9]+\|@\|', '|#|'), '\|#\|\|#\|OUT_END\|[0-9]+\|', '|#|')"/>
             <xsl:variable name="rows" select="tokenize($preRows,'\|#\|')[not(. = '')]"/>
              <xsl:variable name="tokenizedList" select="tokenize($rows[1], '\|\^\|')" />
            <col colNum='1'><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($tokenizedList[1])"/></col>
                   <xsl:for-each select="$rows">
                           <xsl:call-template name="processRows">
                                  <xsl:with-param name="row" select="."/>   
                           </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>          
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
```

I need the following output group by order id.Xml output I am looking for.

```
 

    <orders>
     <order>
         <id>3388892</id>
         <items>
             <item>Product 1</item>
             <qty>4</qty>
             <price>1.99</price>
         </items>
          <items>
             <item>Product 2</item>
             <qty>1</qty>
             <price>0.79</price>
         </items>
          <items>
             <item>Product 3</item>
             <qty>2</qty>
             <price>1.22</price>
         </items>
          <items>
             <item>Product 4</item>
             <qty>1</qty>
             <price>4.33</price>
         </items>
    </order>
    <order>
         <id>3388893</id>
         <items>
             <item>Product 1</item>
             <qty>1</qty>
             <price>1.99</price>
         </items>
          <items>
             <item>Product 2</item>
             <qty>2</qty>
             <price>0.79</price>
         </items>
          <items>
             <item>Product 3</item>
             <qty>3</qty>
             <price>1.22</price>
         </items>
    </order>
    </orders>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be easier to do something like:

**XML**

```
<input>DBSTART|ecec2b45-609c-45b5-a0cb-cc50220eeb9a|2|@|BEGIN|2|@|OUT_START|11|@
|3388892|^|Product 1|^|4|^|1.99|^||#
|3388892|^|Product 2|^|1|^|0.79|^||#
|3388892|^|Product 3|^|2|^|1.22|^||#
|3388892|^|Product 4|^|1|^|4.33|^||#
|3388893|^|Product 1|^|1|^|1.99|^||#
|3388893|^|Product 2|^|2|^|0.79|^||#
|3388893|^|Product 3|^|3|^|1.22|^||#
|OUT_END|11|@|END|2|@|DBEND|ecec2b45-609c-45b5-a0cb-cc50220eeb9a|2|@|</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <xsl:variable name="lines">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\n')[position() gt 1 and position() lt last()]">
            <xsl:variable name="details" select="tokenize(., '\|\^\|')" />
            <items>
                <order>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($details[1], 2)"/>
                </order>
                <item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$details[2]"/>
                </item>
                <qty>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$details[3]"/>
                </qty>
                <price>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$details[4]"/>
                </price>
            </items>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <orders>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$lines/items" group-by="order">
            <order>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </id>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="* except order"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </order>    
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </orders>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
   <order>
      <id>3388892</id>
      <items>
         <item>Product 1</item>
         <qty>4</qty>
         <price>1.99</price>
      </items>
      <items>
         <item>Product 2</item>
         <qty>1</qty>
         <price>0.79</price>
      </items>
      <items>
         <item>Product 3</item>
         <qty>2</qty>
         <price>1.22</price>
      </items>
      <items>
         <item>Product 4</item>
         <qty>1</qty>
         <price>4.33</price>
      </items>
   </order>
   <order>
      <id>3388893</id>
      <items>
         <item>Product 1</item>
         <qty>1</qty>
         <price>1.99</price>
      </items>
      <items>
         <item>Product 2</item>
         <qty>2</qty>
         <price>0.79</price>
      </items>
      <items>
         <item>Product 3</item>
         <qty>3</qty>
         <price>1.22</price>
      </items>
   </order>
</orders>
```